# Sending Discord Messages to external application

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am currently working on a desktop application and I want to get messages sent from Discord to this application. How should I do this?

I have used POST requests and webhooks to send messages TO Discord, but I have never taken messages from a channel and sent them somewhere else.

I know I can do something using on_message like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
       message_content = message.content
       ## send message_content to external application
```

I just am confused on what to use/how to send the messages to the application itself. Keep in mind that this I'm making in Python 3.6.6

Comment: Are the bot and the application running on the same machine? Is one of them started by the other?  If they're on different machines, are they on the same network? Depending on your use case, you can use pipes, sockets, a http service, etc.  The most general of those is probably the socket.

Comment: The Discord bot is going to be hosted on a server. The application is going to be on a users computer (different network, different machines)